# org.ektorp.DbAccessException if POJO not extended from CouchDbDocument

Tags: java, couchdb, ektorp

My java application connects to CouchDB using the Ektorp persistence api http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html to store and retrieve objects. I'm trying to store a simple bean with few String properties and
using CouchDbConnector.create(mybean) to create the document and CouchDbConnector.get(mybean.class,doumentid) to retrieve the document. 
When I extend my bean with CouchDBDocument as documented here http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d100e355, it works well while creating and retrieving the document but if I don't extend it with CouchDBDocument and annotate the "id" and the "revision" attributes as listed here http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d100e31, then create document works but retrieve document throws this exception.

nested exception is org.ektorp.DbAccessException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "_id"

I tried various options by changing the name "id" to "_id" but it do not work. Also, I notice that when I don't extend my bean with CouchDbDocument then in the couchdb, an "id" and "revision" fields are created in the document along with "_id" and "_rev". These fields are not created when I extend CouchDbDocument. Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The id field must serialize to "_id". Write a unit test and verfify that you class can be written to json and read from json with the fields named _id and _rev.

Comment: I had created a very simple class with just one String field and the other two fields are id and revision, both of them are annotated with @JsonProperty("_id")  and @JsonProperty("_rev") but retrieving still throws error.

Comment: I also copied the whole code of CouchDbDocument from <http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ektorp/org.ektorp/1.1.1/org/ektorp/support/CouchDbDocument.java> and just renamed the class name and tried the same but still retrieving throws error. It looks like its expecting a CouchDbDocument object only.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while the question was asked but I'm answering in case someone has the same problem.

The right Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And in your POJO replace `import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.*;` by `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;`